# DLookup Or DMax To Find Value

Tags: ms-access, vba, lookup

I am sure this is fairly simple put I am having trouble getting started on this. I use a Form to invoice clients which includes the field [Billing_Month].  What I'm looking to accomplish is this.  When I create a new invoice, the [Billing_Month] will look to the last invoice created (use [Invoice_#] with DMax?), and populate the value from that that invoices [Billing_Month]

I have thought to use: Billing_Month = DMax ("Billing_Month", "frmInvoices"), but this doesn't specifically get me the last invoice, it would just look for the highest Billing_Month, which is a text field.

I have thought to use: Billing_Month = DLookup ("Billing_Month", "frmInvoices"), But this doesn't get me the last invoice to pull from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a custom function for this - assuming the underlying table is called `tblInvoices`:

```
Function GetBillingMonthOfLatestInvoice()
  Const SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Billing_Month FROM tblInvoices ORDER BY [Invoice_#] DESC"
  Dim RS AS DAO.Recordset
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
  If RS.EOF Then
    GetBillingMonthOfLatestInvoice = Null
  Else
    GetBillingMonthOfLatestInvoice = RS(0)
  End If
End Function
```

### Update

The above code can be generalised to return other related fields like so:

```
Function GetValueForLatestInvoice(FieldToLookUp As String)
  Dim RS As DAO.Recordset, SQL As String
  SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 " + FieldToLookUp + " FROM tblInvoices ORDER BY [Invoice_#] DESC"
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
  If RS.EOF Then
    GetValueForLatestInvoice = Null
  Else
    GetValueForLatestInvoice = RS(0)
  End If
End Function
```

To use, copy the code to a new standard module, then for each relevant text box on the form, set its Default Value property in the Properties window to something like this:

```
=GetValueForLatestInvoice("Billing_Month")
```

That would be for the text box holding the billing month value; for the one holding the billing year, you would use

```
=GetValueForLatestInvoice("Billing_Year")
```

Comment: You are correct that the underlying table is "tblInvoices".  I copied and pasted your function into the Code builder but the first line starting "Const SQL = "Select...." is getting a syntax error.  I am fairly new to VBA, so I may just be overlooking something small.

Comment: @bjk - Apologies, typo - either remove the semi colon at the end of the line entirely (which I've now done in an edit), or move it to be before the final `"`

Comment: @ChrisRollinston Sorry for the dumb question.  Where do I add this? I was hoping to have this fire when I added an account name to frmInvoices, so I typically would add as an event.  Do I need to create a module for this function?  I just can't get it to fire.

Comment: @bjk - (1) go into the VBA editor (Alt+F11), add a new standard module, and paste the code into it; (2) in the form designer, select the billing month text box, and in the Properties window, assign `=GetBillingMonthOfLatestInvoice()` for its Default Value property ('Data' tab)

Comment: Thanks for the instructions.  That worked great!  I have two other fields I would like to do the same thing with; [Billing_Year] & [Bill_Date].  Can I just modify the code, create a new module, etc?

Comment: @bjk - while you can use as many modules as you like, it would be sensible to group related custom functions in the same module. That said, it would be even more sensible to generalise the original function so that you won't need to maintain more than one version of it in the first place - check out my updated answer above.

Comment: I used the updated code and it seems to be working great.  What an awesome approach to this!  Keeps things very simple.  Now to try understand what you did! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of both `DLookup()` and `DMax()` like so:

```
DLookup("Billing_Month","tblInvoices","[Invoice_#]=" & DMax("[Invoice_#]","tblInvoices"))
```

Comment: I ran the code you suggested and nothing happens. There is no syntax error, it just doesn't fire.  I have looked it over and all the variables are correct; "tblInvoices", "Billing_Month", "Invoice_#".  Any thoughts?

Comment: @bjk I just tested the formula and it works correctly for me. A working example is available for download [here](http://wikisend.com/download/600866/billing.zip). Open the table in Datasheet View, then run the macro and a MsgBox will pop up the result. Add a new row to the table (with a different Billing_Month value) and then run the macro again.