# Access 2010 DMAX return value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I saw this link [about the value returned by DMAX in Access 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2bd94099-ddd7-483f-8028-2c6ceea5de15/access-2010-dmax-returns-0-instead-of-null?forum=accessdev)
However, when I test it in my vba code to find the max value, it seems to always skip to set the nullNum to 0. Any help is appreciated.

```
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
If DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG") <> "" Or Not IsNull(DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG")) Or DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG") <> 0 Then
    oldDate = DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG")
Else:
    nullNum = 0
End If
If DMin("[Eff Date]", "203_Differences") > oldDate Or nullNum = 0 Then
       Run Query;
End If
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

My problem is that either A) nullNum is always being set to 0. OR 2) that my logic with the Dmin is incorrect (but let me explain that; I am only running the query if the minimum of the new dates is greater than the oldest of the old dates). I do not think my logic is wrong there.

Comment: Found a workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498398/dlookup-or-dmax-to-find-value. Still interested in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Variant data type can store Null values. Try to get the DMax value and simply check for Null value.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim maxDate As Variant
    maxDate = DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG")

If Not IsNull(maxDate) Then
    If DMin("[Eff Date]", "203_Differences") > maxDate Then
    'Run Query
    End If
End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm! Much appreciated.